# How to keep alive application when app is in suspended (terminate) mode in ios?

Tags: ios

How to keep alive application when app is in suspended (terminate) mode in ios? I need to keep counter awake though terminates the application. Continuously my timer needs to check and call the web services.

Comment: you can use silent notification

Answer (score 0):

Apple say app can't be relaunched after force close, and you can't call the web services when app force close.
Please read apple documantation [link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

But you can use local push notifications.

Comment: Thnx for you reply but can you please elaborate in detail How can I manage it with local push notifications....?

Comment: for objective-c see this tutorial:
http://ashishkakkad.com/2016/09/push-notifications-in-ios-10-objective-c/
for swift see this tutorial:
https://makeapppie.com/2016/08/08/how-to-make-local-notifications-in-ios-10/